# Replace current svg with new svg deleting older DOM elements as well

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bundle-layout

My D3 layout gets dynamically update based on button click. When i try and click on button to update the SVG, it always creates a new SVG below older svg.

As and when i click on button, it keeps on adding new SVG below older SVG.

What I want is it should replace current SVG and create updated chart at same place.
My code is below

```
// JQuery function for two buttons. Based on button click, I am selecting
input file name

$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#link1").click(function(){
    d3.select("#SVG_name").remove();
getData("readme-flare-imports.json");
  });
$("#link2").click(function(){
    d3.select("#SVG_name").remove();
    getData("readme-flare-imports_1.json");
  }
)});


var getData = function(fileName)
{

var diameter = 500,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    innerRadius = radius - 120;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius])
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var bundle = d3.layout.bundle();

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
.interpolate("bundle")
.tension(.85)
.radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
.angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", diameter)
.attr("height", diameter)
.append("g")
.attr("id","SVG_name")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])

svg.call(tip);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

d3.json(fileName, function(error, classes) {
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(packageHierarchy(classes)),
  links = packageImports(nodes);

  link = link
  .data(bundle(links))
  .enter().append("path")
  .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", line);

  node = node
  .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
.enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? 8 : -8; })
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.key; })
  .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
  .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
});

   function mouseovered(d) {
  tip.html("<span style='color:red'>" + d.key + "</span>");
  node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });

  link
  .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
  .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
  .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
  .each(function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });

  node
  .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
  .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; })
  .classed("mouseover", tip.show);
}

function mouseouted(d) {
link
  .classed("link--target", false)
  .classed("link--source", false);

node
  .classed("node--target", false)
  .classed("node--source", false)
  .classed("mouseout",tip.hide);
}



// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
 var map = {};

 function find(name, data) {
   var node = map[name], i;
   if (!node) {
  node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
  if (name.length) {
    node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
    node.parent.children.push(node);
    node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
  }
}
return node;
 }

 classes.forEach(function(d) {
   find(d.name, d);
  });

 return map[""];
}

// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
  imports = [];

  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.name] = d;
  });

  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
  if (d.imports) d.imports.forEach(function(i) {
  imports.push({source: map[d.name], target: map[i]});
  });
 });

return imports;
}
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
<body>
  <div>   
         <button class="btn btn-default ok-button" id="link1"> Link1  </button>
         <button class="btn btn-default ok-button" id="link2"> Link2  </button>
  </div>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
         <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: When you add the SVG onto the page, does it create an element?

Comment: The would deleting that element work?

Comment: @Lugia101101 - I am trying to remove that SVG element. Check code on 3rd line which says     d3.select("").remove(). It is removing the SVG element. But when i try to redraw another SVG, it gets created below first and not on top of first. I suppose some other elements are not getting removed when i do svg.remove()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51002/discussion-between-lugia101101-and-neil)

Comment: Try like this. Wrap that "SVG_Name" into a div. And use jquery to delete the svg inside of it using this `$('div_name').empty()`. This should work for you. If you still face any prob. Provide a sample fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a d3 expert, but this code looks wrong to me:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", diameter)
            .attr("height", diameter)
            .append("g")
            .attr("id","SVG_name")
```

To quote the d3 documentation for append():

> Appends a new element with the specified name as the last child of
>   each element in the current selection, returning a new selection
>   containing the appended elements.

So in actual fact, you are assigning that id to the `<g>`, rather than the `<svg>`.  So your

```
d3.select("#SVG_name").remove();
```

will be removing the `<g>`, not the `<svg>`.

Try this instead:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", diameter)
            .attr("height", diameter)
            .attr("id","SVG_name")
            .append("g")
```